# how to highlight exact match in range

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm not even sure anymore. It seems like this is so simple but apparently not for me. Can you help?

Not even sure what to use: `MATCH`? `COUNTIFS`? `HLOOKUP`? 
I'm trying to: If any of the 'Units' (G3:U3) is an exact match to any of the 'Per Unit' (B3:E:3) then I would like to highlight the cell under 'units' that has a match.

EXAMPLE:
 
G3 is found in B3 so G3 would be highlighted. J3 is found in C3 so J3 would be highlighted. O3 is found in D3 so O3 would be highlighted. I3 is found in E3 so I3 would be highlighted.

And then do the same with next row. only comparing same row results

EXAMPLE 2:
 
K4 is found in B4 so K4 would be highlighted. L4 is found in C4 so L4 would be highlighted. T4 is found in D4 so T4 would be highlighted. N4 is found in E4 so N4 would be highlighted.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QXTgZEZ7Yn8JbVrnZ5dUZvSaOlXkJf4PnnP6Sp_YgLE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

the custom formula for range **G3:U**

```
=MATCH(G3, $B3:$F3, 0)
```

[image: 0]